# Cannot close listening socket to abort accept()/select() from a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, select

I am writing a Python (v3.7.3) socket server for which I want to use blocking I/O. I use `select()` with no timeout for accepting new clients as well as reading from them. I can close the listening socket in order to abort the select(), and catch the OSError as an indication to stop execution.

**However, this doesn't seem to work when ran in a separate thread, and I don't understand why.**

I understand that there are other ways to accomplish this such as using using timeouts, using a dummy socket for select(), or making a dummy connection to the listener to wake it up. But these all somewhat defeat the purpose of using select() and aren't necessary when running in a single thread.

This is a basic example to reproduce the issue and, in my actual code, represents just one thread of many (hence, my use of threading in the first place):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import signal
import socket
import threading


class SocketCloseTest:
    """Simple test case for using socket.close() to abort select.select()"""

    def __init__(self, port, address=None):
        self.port = port
        self.address = address or ''

        self.socket = None

    def stop(self):
        """Close listening socket to stop select.select()"""

        if self.socket:
            print("Closing listener", self.socket)
            self.socket.close()
            print("Listener closed", self.socket)

    def threaded_run(self):
        """Run test in a separate thread"""

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        print("Starting sub-thread")
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        print("Sub-thread ended")

    def run(self):
        """Run test"""

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # Reuse port for quick re-launch of the application
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind((self.address, self.port))
        print("Starting listener")
        self.socket.listen()

        try:
            print("select() started")
            r, w, e = select.select([self.socket], [], [])
        except OSError:
            print("select() aborted")
        else:
            print("select() completed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tester = SocketCloseTest(5000, address='')

    # Set up signal handler for Ctrl-C
    def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        print("Received signal {}".format(signum))
        tester.stop()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    # This works
    tester.run()

    # This doesn't work
    # tester.threaded_run()

    print("Main thread ended")
```

When using `test.run()`, it runs as expected and results in this:

> Starting listener
>   Select started
>   ^CReceived signal 2
>   Closing listener <socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 5000)>
>   Listener closed <socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>
>   Select cancelled
>   Main thread ended

However, when ran with `tester.threaded_run()`, it just hangs where the call to select() should abort. Strangely, placing the job in the background at that point causes the code to continue as it should:

> Starting sub-thread
>   Starting listener
>   Select started
>   ^CReceived signal 2
>   Closing listener <socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 5000)>
>   Listener closed <socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>
>   --Ctrl-Z pressed here to suspend job in shell--
>
> $ bg
>   --Shell reports job in background--
>   Select cancelled
>   Sub-thread ended
>   Main thread ended

Thank you …

- *edited to mention that `accept()` suffers from the exact same symptom.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`close()` won't do what you want in the multithreaded case.  Use one of the other mechanisms you describe instead.

In the single-threaded case, control returns to the `select()`, which is restarted and notices EBADF on the now-dismissed file descriptor.  (This is highly dangerous, of course, because fd #3 might be recycled by any other thread, or even a complex signal handler, at any time, though your toy program appears safe.)  In the multi-threaded case, `close()` just doesn't wake up your `select()`ing thread.

The [Python docs warn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close):

> **Note:** `close()` releases the resource associated with a connection but does not necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close the connection in a timely fashion, call `shutdown()` before `close()`.

In fact, this is a relatively thorny and platform-dependent problem.  Excerpting a [2008 article in the venerable Dr Dobb's](https://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/file-descriptors-and-multithreaded-progr/212001285):

> On some operating systems, [ *shutdown()* instead of *close()* ] is also the only working solution: On FreeBSD, a *close()* without *shutdown()* does not wake up the processes waiting in a *read()* or *select()*....
>
> Another issue to consider is that closing by *shutdown()* or by *close()* may not be considered a read event in the OS....
>
> However, *shutdown()* works only on the sockets with established connections, not on the ones listening for new connections nor on the other kinds of file descriptors....

(For what it's worth, on my system a `shutdown()` *does* awaken the `select()`ing thread.)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent, well-researched answer. Considering the symptoms, this makes perfect sense. It does appear take a deeper understanding of the systems involved (OS, CPython, and the code in question) to piece it all together, which you've done well.

Comment: While I know you recommend against it, I thought I'd see how shutdown() affected my scenario. Like you, it worked, but only some portion of the time for me; other times it still hung, presumably because of race conditions. While it pains me to know I'm not at 100% efficiency, I mitigated by using a timeout and loop-stop flag.

Comment: @PiranhaPhish thank you!  I thought this was a great question and was surprised to learn that the situation was so fraught.